# if selected abc in select element how happen abc group items in second select element

Tags: javascript

there are two select element. if abc value is selected in the first select element abc group items happen in second select element.

I want to do this. This how to make ?

```
<select id="bolum" onChange="giveSelection(this.value)">
  <option value="bp">bp</option>
  <option value="mv">mv</option>
</select>
<select id="ders">
  <option data-option="bp">gorsel</option>
  <option data-option="bp">internet</option>
  <option data-option="mv">vergi</option>
  <option data-option="mv">maths</option>
</select>


var bolum = document.querySelector('#bolum');
var ders = document.querySelector('#ders');
var options2 = ders.querySelectorAll('option');

        function giveSelection(selValue) {

            ders.innerHTML='';

            for(var i = 0; i < options2.length; i++) 
              {
                if(options2[i].dataset.option === selValue) 
                {
                  ders.appendChild(options2[i]);
                }
              }
        }

giveSelection(bolum.value);
```

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask because we can't help you. Please share us the code you have already tried.

Comment: please show us some code, we are not your workers @OnurCevik

Comment: What does "group items happen" even mean?  Clarify the problem and provide an example of where you're stuck.

Comment: I share codes. not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this using jQuery?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id = 'first'>
    <option disabled selected>--select</option>
    <option>ABC</option>
    <option>123</option>
</select>
<select id = 'second' style = 'display:none'>
</select>
<script>
    var optionsAbc = '<option>A</option><option>B</option>';
    var options123 = '<option>1</option><option>2</option>';
    $("#first").change(function() {
        $("#second").show();
        var value = $(this).val();
        if(value == 'ABC') {
            $("#second").html(optionsAbc);
        } else if (value == '123') {
            $("#second").html(options123);
        }
    });
</script>
```